# How do I create tags like stackoverflow?

Tags: php, jquery

I've searched google looking for the jquery/php code to create the tags used when asking a question.  Does anyone have a good reference or example of how this is done.

I'm basically trying to create the multiple blocks allowing a user to remove them by clicking the 'X' I also need to integrate them with my DB tables.

Thanks

Comment: It's a combination of server-side and client-side scripting, html, css, database operations, etc... There's not going to be a reference for this. It's just a combination of individual techniques.

Comment: Visually? Functionally? Logically? All the above? Not trying to be rude: what sort of answers are you expecting? Basic workflow, entire implementation, or somewhere in between? It'll help tremendously when people are formulating their answer.

Comment: @MikeB - he's asking how to implement the user interface.  Perhaps a pop-up of similar looking tags, but certainly the "x" to remove tags.  I don't think the question needs further clarification.  (I had to re-read the question to realize it though.)

Comment: Something like http://webspirited.com/tagit/#demos ??

Comment: Or if you want to research a bit more on your own... Wordpress is opensource and has integrated tag support. So you could look at the source code and try to implement ( or take that one there ) something on yourself.

Comment: check the source: css, html, js. all that is available to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359535/stackoverflow-like-tagging-system