# create stackoverflow tagging system?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a tagging system just like SO has.
I have added the tags,now I want to remove them.

MyQuestion:

- How do I remove the tags appended?
- how do I make the cross button(a span) look identical to that in SO tagging system?

[***SO TAGGING***](http://jsfiddle.net/Wky2Z/5/)

```
var tags = [];
$("#textBox").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag' >"  + this.value+'<span class="cross" onclick="remove_tag()">X</span>'+ "</a>");

        function remove_tag(){
        //what to do here?
        }
        tags.push(this.value);
        this.value = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: naa..I dont need any js for this...i think 25 lines of code would be perfect for such task..check the fiddle,adding is done..removal is remaining

Comment: in reply to question 2 - looking at the source code they use a sprite image for the X

Comment: Since you are defining the remove_tag function inside of the keypress callback, it does not fall within the scope of when the onclick event is triggered.  Try defining that function outside of where you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wky2Z/11/

Basically, listen on the `.cross` to be clicked, and then **remove from array** and **delete element**

```
//enter something in textbox and press enter....
var tags = [];
$("#textBox").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag' >"  + this.value+'<span class="cross">X</span>'+ "</a>");


        tags.push(this.value);
        this.value = "";
    }
});

$('body').on('click','.cross',function(){

    tags.splice($(this).parent('a').html(), 1);
    $(this).parent('a').remove();
});
```

As for the look of the cross, SO use a CSS Sprite, so you can do the same by making a png or gif or jpeg of the two states, off(grey) and hover(red) and switch the `background-position` to red with css eg: `.cross:hover { background-position:0px -20px }`

Answer (score 1):

You can delete elements making use of [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
Also, i would recommend you to make use of jQuery events instead of using inline events. (if you take a look at the source code of stackoverflow you will notice there are no inline javascript calls)

In this case you would need to add an event handler to the `document` object as you want to assign the events to elements which are not loaded in the DOM from the start.

```
$(document).on('click', '.tag span', function(){
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/Wky2Z/7/

## Update

I updated the example removing the element from the list of tags too: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Wky2Z/8/

Added a `data-value` for the tag links:

```
$(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag' data-value='" + this.value + "' >"  + this.value+'<span class="cross">X</span>'+ "</a>");
```

And modified the click event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tag span', function(){
   $(this).parent().remove();
   var removeItem = $(this).parent().data('value');

   tags = $.grep(tags, function(value) {
       return value != removeItem;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For a full jQuery solution you can remove the inline `remove_tag` function and use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function. it works for dynamically created elements too.

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the
>   selected elements.

Here you can get the parent element of the deleted element and remove it from the DOM using `remove`.

To "sync" the array with the current situation you can use [`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to delete the item from the array; note the `removedItem` variable used to get the text only of the parent excluding the children from the text.

Code:

```
//enter something in textbox and press enter....
var tags = [];
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body').on('click', 'span.cross', function () {
        var removedItem = $(this).parent().contents(':not(span)').text();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        tags = $.grep(tags, function (value) {
            return value != removedItem;
        });
    });

    $("#textBox").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag' >" + this.value + '<span class="cross">X</span>' + "</a>");

            tags.push(this.value);
            this.value = "";
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/pDFnG/

Comment: Basically is the same I suggested but you are using `contents` instead of using a `data` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/Wky2Z/6/

Move `remove_tag` outside of keypress event handle and pass a `this` pointer to it for quick solution:

```
//enter something in textbox and press enter....
var tags = [];

function remove_tag(x) {
    $(x).parent('a').remove();
}
$(function () {
    $("#textBox").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag' >" + this.value + '<span class="cross" onclick="remove_tag(this)">X</span>' + "</a>");

            tags.push(this.value);
            this.value = "";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: should I write this remove_tag(x) function outside dom ready?

Comment: @VAGABOND yes outside

Comment: @rtpHarry:but then the tags array goes out of scope?is it ok if i place it inside dom ready?

Comment: @VAGABOND Why are you using the `tags` array?

Comment: I think you need to incorporate array.splice like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13361892/156388 into the remove_tag() method to keep your tags array in sync with the UI.

Comment: It was difficult to choose any one answer,hence upvoted every answer and the ticked the most complete answer...